# How do I get a USB GI1515 modem working?

Tags: usb-modem

Brand new to Ubuntu.
Trying to install a GI1515 USB modem. Where can I find the driver package please?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on an old EeePC 701 4g with 512mb RAM.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!